# Jenkins Service connection in Azure devops giving error

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I have a Jenkins instance hosted in AWS and I have created a Job to trigger test execution in aws VM. Now I'm creating a service connection in Azure devops to trigger this job whenever there is a build triggered in azure release pipeline.

But I'm getting below error while creating service connection. This jenkins URL is publicly accessible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Make sure the Url is correct with `http/https`
2. Enable the `Accept untrusted SSL certificates (optional)`
3. Double-check the `UserName` and `Password`. If the issue persists, use Token instead of password (Jenkins Configure > API Token > Add new Token)
4. If both Password and Token can't work, you can enter the Service Connection name and then **Save without verification**.

   [image]

It seems there's something wrong with verify step in some cases, so you can ignore the verification and use the service connection directly in your task. Check these two tickets. ([Issue1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/2740#issuecomment-251121741), [Issue2](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9468))